# Why was Yoda unable to defeat Sidious in their final confrontation in RotS?

Tags: star-wars

Throughout this [scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JV2x3p_Qn8&ab_channel=FilmicBox) it appears that Yoda is the more skilled and focused in his confrontation with Sidious even though Sidious landed the first blow with his force lightning. This is also coupled with the fact that Sidious was injured greatly in his earlier fight with Mace Windu who he lost to even though his skills are below Yoda's

However, the implication at the end of this scene is that both force users are well matched with each other and can be seen as equals in skill

So what ultimately allowed Sidious to draw in the fight?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What was the reason Yoda did not continue his fight with Sidious?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/158162/what-was-the-reason-yoda-did-not-continue-his-fight-with-sidious) The duplicate explains that your premise here is wrong and that they were not equals, Sidious was more powerful.

Comment: Defeating who is probably the most powerful Jedi made the Sith victory complete and also narrative wise you couldn't make a defeated person an Emperor.